# Equivalent of iOS' 30/30 (task manager) app for OS X

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, mac-appstore, productivity

[30/30](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/30-30/id505863977?mt=8) is a slick task manager for iOS devices that's also free. I'm trying to find an equivalent app for OS X. Some of the features in 30/30 that I would like to see in a mac app are:

- Clean interface
- Cycle a set of tasks ad infinitum (good for those long `code-coffee-code-reddit-read-coffee-...` cycles)
- Start/stop/pause a task and adjust a task's time temporarily (e.g. +5/-5 mins)
- Free or less than $5

Does anyone know of such an app? Here's a screenshot of 30/30 on an iPhone.

[image]

Comment: P.S. Some of the requirements can be relaxed, for reasonable definitions of "relaxed"...

Answer (score 1):

There's the Reminders app in Mavericks, but you can also try Anxiety: http://www.anxietyapp.com

Answer (score 1):

I use [pushbullet](https://www.pushbullet.com/) to get the iOS notification show up to Mac.
This way, you can still use 30/30 app on your iPhone, but get notification on your Mac.

Answer (score 1):

I found an app called FocusList which I use to do a similar thing to 30/30, it lets you plan your day and tasks in order and go Pomodoro style through them one by one. It isn't quite as cute as 30/30, but gave me what I needed. It's under $5 so not free like 30/30, and it looks like you can only do things in 30m (25m + 5m break).

http://focuslist.co/